# Создание REST API Java EE

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, rest

**Дано**: встала задача написания простенького `REST API`, состоящего буквально из нескольких методов. На вход подаем несколько параметров, на выходе `JSON`. Нет необходимости работать через браузер, то есть никаких страниц красивого отображения всего этого не требуется(может тогда даже более корректно это назвать `Веб-сервисом`?). Нагрузка предполагается небольшая.

Естественно потребуется какая либо авторизация. В голове сложилась такая схема: при успешной авторизации пользователю передается токен, который в дальнейшем передается при каждом запросе к API. На бэкэнде соответственно проверка этого токена.

**Что имею**:

- так как `Java` мне наиболее близка, выбор пал на нее;
- сборка `maven`;
- в качестве фреймворка был выбран `Spring`;
- сервер `Apache Tomcat` v8;
- текущая база `MSSQL`.

**Вопрос**: насколько данный стек технологий целесообразен для решения такой задачи, не является ли это "стрельбой из пушки по воробьям"?

Где то слышал что `Tomcat` не поддерживает Java EE, или не полностью поддерживает, так ли это?

Вопрос конечно общий, но хотелось бы знать ваше мнение, что бы заведомо не пойти ложным путем.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

PS: про `Node.js` слышал, но как то не сложилось по техническим причинам)
А может не заморачиваться и заюзать `PHP`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да. Tomcat это просто сервлет-контейнер и по сути не является J2EE-сервером, т.к. не имплементирует все необходимые EE-спецификации. Но они вам и не нужны, если вы используете Spring-фреймворк.

Выбранные вами технологии вполне подойдут для решения вашей задачи.

Также советую для легкого конфигурирования использовать **Spring Boot**, который обеспечит вам множество уже готовых возможностей.
Для работы с БД обратите внимание на **Spring Data-JPA**.

В вашем случае даже можно еще более упростить решение, используя **Spring Data-Rest**

[Пример](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) того как можно за 15минут создать простой RESTfull веб-сервис на Spring Data-Rest и Spring Boot.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Да, как раз таки на данный момент мучаю Spring Boot. А вот скажите по поводу всяких  Spring Data-JPA и  Spring Data-Rest, я из БД дергаю только хранимые процедуры, а во всех туториалах происходят манипуляции именно с таблицами БД. В таком случае мне наверно незачем использовать данные технологии?

Comment: @droid Если вы вообще планируете использовать JPA то хранимки можно дергать из Spring репозиториев, просто навесив соотв. аннотацию (см [jpa.stored-procedures](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.stored-procedures)). На мой взгляд очень удобно, красиво и лаконично. В противном случае(без JPA) можете использовать более low-level вариант cо [Spring JDBC](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-StoredProcedure)

Comment: да ок, спасибо.