# Средства для разработки веб-сервиса Java

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, веб-служба

Необходимо создать приложение в виде:

1. Приложение должно быть распределено по 3-ем отдельным серверам.
2. Сервер СУБД: СУБД для размещения базы данных.
3. Сервер Приложений 1: используется для размещения серверной части приложения, представленной Моделью на основе ORM технологии.
4. Сервер Приложений 2: используется для размещения клиентского веб-приложения.

Для реализации ORM технологии взаимодействия СУБД и серверной части выбран Hibernate. Для реализации клиентского приложения выбран Spring MVC.Серверная часть должна быть реализована в виде веб-сервиса, для ее реализации выбран REST подход.

Вопрос:

- Есть ли отдельная какая-то реализация Spring для разработки веб-сервисов или даже конкретно REST веб-сервисов?
  Интересно обоснованное мнение опытных разработчиков по выбранным средствам разработки.

Comment: Это будет очень странно, если в спринге не окажется ничего для рестфула.

Comment: @Sergey, можно подробнее?

Comment: Подробнее только здесь разве что https://spring.io/ Сам-то со спрингом не работаю. Просто знаю, что есть такой и примерно какие там функции, на всякий пожарный.

Comment: @bsuart В спринге есть много чего для разработки Rest - сервисов. А главное их разработка не представляет каких-либо усилий. Достаточно реализовать соотв слой контроллеров в Spring MVC. В интернете куча материалов по этому вопросу. Посмотрите, например [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625503/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-rest-api-java-ee/626221#626221) вопрос с моим ответом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самое простое это использовать Spring boot с зависимостью spring-boot-starter-web. Там "с коробки" поддерживается rest: конвертирование объекта в json, обработка HTTP запросов. 
Для начала туториал: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/